# How get the result of classification from svmPredict() in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to see the result of classification done by svmPredcit() in opencv. I have implemented two ways to see the result. First, to see the distance from boundary of classification. Second, to see the result of prediction (yes or no).

```
    float predict = svm.predict(tryme, true);
    cout<<"\n The result of prediction is:  "<<predict;

    bool result = svm.predict(tryme, false);
    cout<<"\n The result of prediction in bool:  "<<result<<"\n";
```

**Problem:** Although The value of predict changes with the change in input image (sometimes -ve sometimes +ve) but still i am always getting "1" from the second cout statement (i.e. the value of result is always one).

Comment: you had to feed in an array of 'labels' to the training, remember ? the one, that fits your svm.predict() value closest is the anwer.

Comment: @Berak: yes, i did it. I put the labels when i trained my svm. And, i think that is why the value of `predict` is changing (-ve or +ve). But why i am unable to get the value in `result`/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your labels are `+1` and `-1`  your code should be

```
    bool result = svm.predict(tryme, false) > 0.0f;
```

Converting both +1.0f and -1.0f to bool results in `true`

Comment: Thanks, now it is giving me results in 0 and 1. But could me please tell me what `>0.0f` is doing?

Comment: It is an expression that is testing whether the output of `svm.predict()` is greater than zero.